# Working with VS2008/3.5 ASP AJAX site on a 2.0sp1/AJAX Extesnion 1.0 server?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

I am currently developing in 3.5 (building to 3.5 as I am using LINQ) and deploying my code to a 2.0 server.  I have been successful in this so far, but now I am trying to utilize some of the ASP AJAX tools and I am running into an error I can't seem to get around.

First I received

"Unknown server tag 'asp:ScriptManager'."

To which I added this to my web.config controls section:

"add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

this produced the following error which I'm not sure how to correct:

"The base class includes the field 'ScriptManager1', but its type (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager)."

Any thoughts or ideas on this one?

Comment: Co-worker was just having this same problem yesterday. I love this - "but its type (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project, when it was built was referencing the version of System.Web.Extensions for .NET 3.5, which when it is trying to work now it has issues.

You will need to ensure that all references are pointing to the 1.0.61025.0 version, and that NO references to the .NET 3.5 ones are included.